# How do I run an iPad emulator?

Tags: macos, ipad, ios-simulator

I have no real need for the entire SDK, my project involves mainly JS and CSS on an ePub structure. My fiend lend me his MacBook on which I'm typing now.

I can create everything on a PC box, import to the MacBook and than test it on the emulator.

How do I install an iPad emulator on a MacBook ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only way to install the iPhone/iPad simulator is to install the SDK.